# Airflow rerun a single task multiple times on success

Tags: airflow

What is the best way to rerun a task (A) 3 times sequentially?:

That is task A -> task A -> task A -> task B

I ask because I will run another separate data validation task (B) that will compare the data from those 3 separate runs.

So this is what I have done so far:

```pyhton
dag = DAG("hello_world_0", description="Starting tutorial", schedule_interval='* * * * *',
          start_date=datetime(2019, 1, 1),
          catchup=False)

data_pull_1 = BashOperator(task_id='attempt_1', bash_command='echo "Hello World - 1!"',dag=dag)
data_pull_2 = BashOperator(task_id='attempt_2', bash_command='echo "Hello World - 2!"',dag=dag)
data_pull_3 = BashOperator(task_id='attempt_3', bash_command='echo "Hello World - 3!"',dag=dag)

data_validation = BashOperator(task_id='data_validation', bash_command='echo "Data Validation!"',dag=dag)


data_pull_1 >> data_pull_2 >> data_pull_3 >> data_validation
```

This might work but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: are those 3 task A independent to each other?

Comment: Those three tasks should run one after another (ideally after a success) i.e. Task A runs (is successful), Task A runs again (is successful), Task A runs one final time (is successful). Finally Task B is called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try below implementation, we create 3 operations by using for loop

```python
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

dag = DAG(
    "hello_world_0",
    description="Starting tutorial",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2019, 1, 1),
    catchup=False
)

chain_operators = []
max_attempt = 3
for attempt in range(max_attempt):
    data_pull = BashOperator(
        task_id='attempt_{}'.format(attempt),
        bash_command='echo "Hello World - {}!"'.format(attempt),
        dag=dag
    )
    chain_operators.append(data_pull)

data_validation = BashOperator(task_id='data_validation', bash_command='echo "Data Validation!"', dag=dag)
chain_operators.append(data_validation)

# Add downstream
for i,val in enumerate(chain_operators[:-1]):
    val.set_downstream(chain_operators[i+1])
```

I changed schedule_interval to None, because with `'* * * * *'` job will be triggered continuously

Comment: Thanks .. I slightly modified your answer for dependencies.