# How ti create looping task to run multiple time in Airflow?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, dependencies, airflow

I need to do this:

```
for i in range(5):
   step1 = PythonOperator(
   .... 
   )


#dependencies

step1 >> step1 >> step1 >> step1 >> step1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Airflow create looping task to run multiple time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67116752/airflow-create-looping-task-to-run-multiple-time)

Answer (score 0):

If you want task `i` to depend on task `i-1`, here is a simple solution that keeps a reference to the previous task and uses it to set the dependency for the current task:

```py
def job(i):
    print(f"Executing task {i}")

with DAG(
    "SO_74208401",
    start_date=datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 2),
    schedule=None,
) as dag:

    previous_task = None

    for i in range(5):
        task = PythonOperator(
            task_id=f"task_{i}",
            python_callable=job,
            op_args=[i]
        )
        
        if previous_task:
            previous_task >> task
        
        previous_task = task
```

[image: tasks]