# Modelling ParallelFor in DAG with Airflow / Cloud Composer

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer

I want to create a DAG to run in Google Cloud Composer. The workflow contains a ParallelFor and I don´t know how to model that.

The workflow looks something like this:

```
task1 >> task2 >> task3 >> task4
```

where task2 splits data into x arrays. Now, I want to run task3 in parallel for these x arrays. Task3 outputs something and task4 combines the outputs.

(you can find a picture of the workflow here: https://github.com/Apollo-Workflows/Sentiment-Analysis)

For now, I have two possible ideas how it could work:

1. There is an easy syntax for it (like `>>` for sequential execution). But I did not found such syntax
2. Working with sub-DAGs. My idea was to append task2 so that it creates x subDAGs (one for each array). The subDAG is basically task3. After all subDAGs are finished, their output is forwarded to task4. Is that possible? If yes, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for my problem. It follows my first possible solution idea. Just use the mechanics from this link:

[Airflow rerun a single task multiple times on success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54756276/airflow-rerun-a-single-task-multiple-times-on-success)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54756276/airflow-rerun-a-single-task-multiple-times-on-success/54764267#54764267) you mentioned as a possible idea, points on the direction on how to run a task after the previous one has ended.

To run dags in parallel you should follow a structure similar to this

```python
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

dag = DAG("dag_paralel", description="Starting tutorial", schedule_interval=None,
          start_date=datetime(2019, 1, 1),
          catchup=False)

task_1 = BashOperator(task_id='task_1', bash_command='echo "This is task 1!"',dag=dag)
task_2 = BashOperator(task_id='task_2', bash_command='echo "This is task 2!"',dag=dag)

task_list = []
max_attempt = 3
for attempt in range(max_attempt):
    data_pull = BashOperator(
        task_id='task_3_{}'.format(attempt),
        bash_command='echo "This is task - 3_{}!"'.format(attempt),
        dag=dag
    )
    task_list.append(data_pull)


data_validation = BashOperator(task_id='task_final', bash_command='echo "We are at the end"',dag=dag)


task_1 >> task_2 >> task_list

task_list >> data_validation
```

This is the DAG structure obtained by this method

[image]